# Multiselect Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, multi-select

How to add a field SearchSources as multiselect kendo ui when you press AddNewRubrica in kendo grid ASP.NET MVC

My Model:

```
public class Rubrica 
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string LookUps { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    [UIHint("SearchSourcesEditor")]
    public IEnumerable<SearchSource> SearchSources { get; set; }
}

public class SearchSource
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

SearchSourcesEditor.cshtml:

```
@using oko.Models

@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@model IEnumerable<SearchSource>

    @( Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
        .DataTextField("Url")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .BindTo((IEnumerable<SearchSource>)ViewData["searchSources"]))
```

Comment: if the question is not clear, please ask

Answer (score -1):

**In mvc view page :**

```
<label for="required">show lable string value</label>
    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                    .Name("required")
                    .Placeholder("Select...")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .DataSource
            (dataSource => dataSource
                    .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("ActionApi", new { controller = "Home", action = "ReadMultiSelect" })))
                    )
    )
```

**In Model :**

```
[UIHint("View Page Name")]
        public string Column-field-name{ get; set; }
```

**In Mvc Controller :**

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ReadMultiSelect()
    {
        var model = Getvalues();
        return Json(model);

    }

[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Getvalues()
    {
    // Object of your model 
            var result = new List<Your-Model-Name>();

            // your logic here....
             .......................................

    // please note : always return in Json : if you dont do this you never get record in multiselect.

     return Json(result);
    }
```